# How to connect SQL Server BDC (Big Data Cluster) from Oracle Enviornment

Tags: sql-server, bigdata

I have SQL Server BDC and clients have multiple sources like Oracle, SAP and external sources. They want to connect to SQL Server BDC. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: They can connect to the Master Instance using TDS like any normal SQL Server. The trick is authentication... is your BDC Active Directory-integrated, using AzAD, or something else?

Comment: yes it is integrated using AZ AD. Now what will be the steps to connect SQL BDC from Oracle Enviornment  or any reference link to refer to?